# Sudden error with Eclipse and Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat

I was doing my webapplication and it worked until today. I turned on, I started the server and now I receive this error, in addition to the fact that the pages in java no longer work. 
I don't have modify any java page. Only some jsp o html.
I also tried to restart Mysql but it did not change:

```
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVVERTENZA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:WebApplication1' did not find a matching property.
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVVERTENZA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:HotelReservation' did not find a matching property.
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.8
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Server built:          Apr 27 2018 19:32:00 UTC
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Server number:         9.0.8.0
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: OS Name:               Mac OS X
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: OS Version:            10.13.5
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Architecture:          x86_64
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: JVM Version:           1.8.0_161-b12
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/albertomiceli/eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: CATALINA_HOME:         /Library/Tomcat
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/albertomiceli/eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Library/Tomcat
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/Users/albertomiceli/eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Library/Tomcat/endorsed
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMAZIONI: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/albertomiceli/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAZIONI: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAZIONI: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAZIONI: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAZIONI: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAZIONI: Initialization processed in 914 ms
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAZIONI: Starting service [Catalina]
lug 12, 2018 11:50:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAZIONI: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.8
lug 12, 2018 11:50:51 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAZIONI: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
lug 12, 2018 11:50:54 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAZIONI: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
lug 12, 2018 11:50:56 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAZIONI: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
lug 12, 2018 11:50:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAZIONI: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
lug 12, 2018 11:50:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAZIONI: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
lug 12, 2018 11:50:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMAZIONI: Server startup in 8960 ms
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
Thu Jul 12 11:51:00 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
lug 12, 2018 11:51:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/HotelReservation] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred when flushing data] with root cause
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.ensureOpen(JspWriterImpl.java:187)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:105)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:180)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:120)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.jsp.prenotazione_jsp._jspService(prenotazione_jsp.java:222)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:444)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:412)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1385)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

lug 12, 2018 11:52:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAZIONI: Marking servlet [Login] as unavailable
lug 12, 2018 11:52:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Allocate exception for servlet [Login]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hotel.Login
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1292)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1032)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:412)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1385)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Why I receive this error? Why i don't understand.

Comment: Check the deployment assembly and check the java class folder there.And also check it jdk path in your project property in eclipse.Also check jsp file correct define the package

Answer (score 0):

try to clean the project going on project -> clean... 
you can also restart eclipse who sometimes just goes crazy

Comment: I have tried but nothing.. I don't understand why it don't connect to DB anymore.

Comment: you get a classNotFoundException on Hotel.login
this means that at runtime the JVM is not able to find the path where that class is.